# Update Parent table from Child table in ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have 2 tables; WorkSchedule(Parent) and WorkShiftBid(Child). Right now, I am able to update `WSBidStatus` to "Approved" when the button in my `WorkShiftBid` view page is pressed.

I have a status column (`WorkScheduleStatus`&`WSBidStatus`) in both tables and what i want is for example when the button is pressed, both Status will be updated to "Approved" where `WorkScheduleID` in both tables are the same.

How should my controller look like to do this?

Model:

```
namespace Website.Models
{
    public class WorkScheduleModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid WorkScheduleID { get; set; }

        public string WorkScheduleStatus { get; set; }
    }

    public class WorkShiftBidModel
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid WorkShiftBidID { get; set; }

        public string WSBidStatus { get; set; }

        public Guid WorkScheduleID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("WorkScheduleID")]
        public WorkScheduleModel WorkSchedules { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> WorkShiftBid(Guid? id)
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand();
            SqlDataReader dr;

            connectionString();
            con.Open();
            com.Connection = con;
            com.CommandText = "update WorkShiftBid set WSBidStatus ='Approved' where WorkShiftBidID = @id ";
            com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id);
            dr = com.ExecuteReader();

            var workShiftBidModel = await _context.WorkShiftBid.FindAsync(id);

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                con.Close();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(WorkShiftBid));
            }
            else
            {
                con.Close();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(WorkShiftBid));
            }

            void connectionString()
            {
                con.ConnectionString = ".........................";
            }
        }
```

View:

```
@model IEnumerable<WorkShiftBidModel>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td> 
            <th>
                .
                .
                .
            </th>
            <form method="post">
                <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Approve" asp-route-id="@item.WorkShiftBidID" asp-action="WorkShiftTab" asp-controller="Manager" />
            </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but are you utilizing both Entity Framework and SqlCommands?

Nevertheless, you can find the Parent Key and update it via a SQL Command like so:

```
UPDATE WorkScheduleModel SET Status = 'Approved' WHERE Id = {ID}
```

Replace {Id} with the Key of your parent record.